# How to close ports in Linux?

Tags: tcp, nmap

I have some question in closing port, I think I got some strange things.

When I use execute

```
nmap --top-ports 10 192.168.1.1
```

it shows that 23/TCP port is open.

But when I execute

```
nmap --top-ports 10 localhost
```

it show that 23/tcp port is closed.

Which of them is true? I want to close this port on my whole system, how can I do it?

Comment: they are both true. TCP ports aren't associated with hosts. they are associated with network interfaces. the difference is subtle but important. interfaces are often the same as hosts, but not always. in this case (as stated in answers) `localhost` is accessing the `lo` (loopback) interface. the IP Address is accesing your real interface, probably `eth0` or `wlan0` or somesuch.

Comment: The apparent naivety of this question led to some terrific answers. Thank you for the question!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Nmap is a great port scanner, but sometimes you want something more authoritative. You can ask the kernel what processes have which ports open by using the `netstat` utility:

```
me@myhost:~$ sudo netstat -tlnp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address   Foreign Address   State    PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53    0.0.0.0:*         LISTEN   1004/dnsmasq    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22      0.0.0.0:*         LISTEN   380/sshd        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631   0.0.0.0:*         LISTEN   822/cupsd       
tcp6       0      0 :::22           :::*              LISTEN   380/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631         :::*              LISTEN   822/cupsd
```

The options I have given are:

- `-t` TCP only
- `-l` Listening ports only
- `-n` Don't look up service and host names, just display numbers
- `-p` Show process information (requires root privilege)

In this case, we can see that `sshd` is listening on any interface (`0.0.0.0`) port 22, and `cupsd` is listening on loopback (`127.0.0.1`) port 631. Your output may show that `telnetd` has a local address of `192.168.1.1:23`, meaning it will not answer to connections on the loopback adapter (e.g. you can't `telnet 127.0.0.1`).

There are other tools that will show similar information (e.g. `lsof` or `/proc`), but netstat is the most widely available. It even works on Windows (`netstat -anb`). BSD netstat is a little different: you'll have to use [sockstat(1)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sockstat&sektion=1) to get the process information instead.

Once you have the process ID and program name, you can go about finding the process and killing it if you wish to close the port. For finer-grained control, you can use a firewall (iptables on Linux) to limit access to only certain addresses. You may need to disable a service startup. If the PID is "-" on Linux, it's probably a kernel process (this is common with NFS for instance), so good luck finding out what it is.

Note: I said "authoritative" because you're not being hindered by network conditions and firewalls. If you trust your computer, that's great. However, if you suspect that you've been hacked, you may not be able to trust the tools on your computer. Replacing standard utilities (and sometimes even system calls) with ones that hide certain processes or ports (a.k.a. rootkits) is a standard practice among attackers. Your best bet at this point is to make a forensic copy of your disk and restore from backup; then use the copy to determine the way they got in and close it off.

Answer (score 16):

To "close" the port you can use `iptables`

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 23 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j DROP
```

Comment: In this answer, "closing the port" means "ignoring any traffic to it". The port is still open, but it cannot be reached anymore. Also note that `DROP` does as it says, it sees the packet and then ignores it. Normally (without iptables enabled), the kernel would send an ICMP port unreachable packet back (which can be simulated with the `REJECT` target instead of `DROP`).

Comment: @Lekensteyn ICMP port unreachable is for UDP. The proper packet to reply with is a TCP RST packet, which can also be generated using the `REJECT` target by writing `-j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset`.

Comment: Despite its lower score, this is the very first answer to actually answer the question. Whoever can add more scores here, please do so.

Answer (score 14):

A Linux system has a so called loopback interface, which is for internal communication. Its hostname is `localhost` and its IP address is `127.0.0.1`.

When you run `nmap` on `localhost`, you actually run the portscan on the **virtual** loopback interface. `192.168.1.1` is the IP address of your **physical** (most likely `eth0`) interface.

So you've run `nmap` on two different network interfaces, this is why there's a difference in the open ports. They are both true.

If you have TCP port 23 open, it is likely that you have a `telnet` server running (which is not a good thing due to its lack of encryption) or you have some kind of trojan horse on your machine.

Comment: so how can i close it?

Comment: @user74080 You can add an `iptables` rule as a nearby answer suggests, but it will keep the service going unused, which consumes resources. So if you have `telnetd` running, just shut it down.

Answer (score 2):

If you do `nmap localhost`, it tells you about a different situation: some programs on linux work as server although they are used only locally. This is because other programs use them like a server they connect to. **So both answers are true, since you ask something different.**

Port 23 is used for telnet. Normally not used anymore. Try to do `nmap -sV 192.168.1.1` to find out which program opens the port.

(192... is a local network IP, so the result of `nmap <your outside world IP>` will also give a different result, because of possible firewall settings etc)

Answer (score 1):

*If* you have a service running and listening on port 23, it is arguably cleaner to ***stop*** the process that listens to port 23 (probably `telnet`) than to keep it running and ***close or block*** port 23 using `iptables`.

When there's no process listening on a port, even in the absence of a firewall block, any attempt to connect to it should result in an immediate "connection refused" (`ECONNREFUSED` to `connect(2)`)

One way to find the process (and its pid) that listens on port 23, if there's such process, is:

```
sudo lsof -i -P | grep ':23 '
```

In the above `-i` lists open internet ports (both UDP and TCP), and -P inhibits translation of ports to service names (via `/etc/services`)

After you found the running process listening on port 23, you can figure out how it got started by looking at the process tree (with say, `pstree`).  If its parent is `init` (very likely), you may recursively search for the name of the process under `/etc`.  e.g.:

```
sudo grep -r telnet /etc
```

This should lead you to the best way to disable it from running in the 1st place.

Comment: There's no need to use grep (and if there were, no need for quotes). You can use `sudo lsof -Pi :23`.

Comment: The quotes are there for a good reason. To make sure only the telnet port (`23`) is matched.  If you don't include a space after the `:23` it will match `:234`, `:2345` etc.

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes sense for grep. Incidentally, it seems that the command without grep (`lsof -Pi :23`) looks for an exact match.