# How to trace this IP

Tags: networking, fedora, ip, background-process

Using nethogs on fedora, I see this process which I never seen before, I hate the fact that it's there, I want to trace it and remove it

[image]

The IP I see

```
 ? root     ..2.168.1.5:59060-52.216.              0.000       0.011 KB/sec
```

And many others as indicated in the screenshot, I suspect it's a malware, running clamav as we speak, but I don't think it will catch anything, hence I'm asking this question.

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Comment: Well, it's unclear. That's two partial IP numbers. Can't do much with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't "trace and remove an IP", but you can kill the process holding a specific port on your system.

I'm assuming that the IP number ending in `2.168.1.5` is your machine.

To figure out what's using port 59060, do

```
$ sudo lsof -i :59060
```

See also [How to close ports in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140021/how-to-close-ports-in-linux)

Comment: thank you, here's upvote from me, I tried that didn't output anything, and now the process stopped working, I'll accept your answer tomorrow morning, giving other people time to answer and giving me time to further investigate the issue